# What is the meaning of ''everglow''?

Tags: meaning

Coldplay use this word in their new song *Everglow*. Some people on the internet do too. However, I can't find the meaning of this word in the dictionary.

Does this word actually exist? If so, what is its meaning?

Answer (score 3):

**ever-** can be used as a prefix having the sense of "always" or "continuously". (E.g. [Macmillan online](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/ever_2)]

Short of a formal definition, you can assume that "everglow" carries the sense of *glowing always or continuously*.

From the song itself:

> There's a light that you give me/ When I'm in shadows 
>   /It's a feeling within me, everglow.
>
> … the light that you left me will everglow …

The sense seems to be that the "light" bestowed upon the narrator by the beloved will glow forever.

Answer (score 0):

Chris Martin said that he heard a surfer say the word Everglow.
I think it means a feeling after you stop feeling sad. That tiny bit of hope or light that you feel after you have been through something big. A light, a glow, a happiness. Something like that.
I like how we can't find an exact meaning of the word. It leaves much for your own interpretation. Coldplay is best known for that lol.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Our site is not geared toward analysis of lyrics (as sites like Lyreka or SongMeanings.com might be), and indeed the original question is asking for a definition rather than an interpretation of them. In any case, we favor answers which are supported by references or examples and not merely personal opinions. I encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for further guidance.

Comment: Objective interpretations are acceptable.

Comment: The Mae band released an album in 2005 called The Everglow, one of the best albums I’ve ever heard, a masterpiece, the album includes a song titled The Everglow, a wonderful song, better than this Everglow of Coldplay. So Martin can say what he wants but all of you should know where he got the name.

Answer (score 0):

"Everglow" by Coldplay is about the feeling of warmth or happiness that comes with the sadness you feel when you think about a relationship, situation, or friendship that has now ended.

Comment: hammad, is that merely your personal interpretation, or can you [edit] your answer to include an authoritative source for this explanation? Note that we're not your typical Q&A site: unsourced personal views are generally discouraged, and are often downvoted. You might like to review [answer] and take our [Tour] for further guidance. :-)

Answer (score -1):

Ever glow means a feeling of bliss and excitement the most happy thing, it can also mean a feeling of hope when the worst is over like after crying.